# Why out is Integer instead of c_double?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have no idea why OUT = integer value as I declared it to c_double?

Basically, my DLL is very simple i.e. X + Y = Z

```
enter code here
import ctypes
from sys import exit
X = ctypes.c_double(6.97)
Y = ctypes.c_double(5.18)
out=ctypes.c_double()
DLLHANDLE = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Walter\\Pyhton_Examples\\Math\\SharedLib.dll")
out = DLLHANDLE.SimpleMath(X,Y)
print("Addition:",out)
exit()
```

Output result as below,

```
 ('Addition:', 0)
 type (out)
 <type 'int'>
```

Noticed that, out = int and no idea why???and the out result should be in c_double ie 12.15 but display as 0.

Please advice.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you assign `ctypes.c_double()` to `out`; what matters is what `DLLHANDLE.SimpleMath(X,Y)` returns, since `out` will refer to that no matter what it used to refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to tell `DLL.SimpleMath` to return a `c_double`. AFAIK this is done with `DLL.SimpleMath.restype = c_double`.

Setting `out = c_double()` and overwriting it later with another object will have no consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`out = ctypes.c_double(DLLHANDLE.SimpleMath(X,Y))`

this should transform your integer to c_double.